# SQL Server 2005 - Inserting records using OpenXML vs delimited string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, openxml

I have a bunch of employee names which need to be inserted in a table.

Should I represent my data like this and use OpenXML to insert into the database:-

```
<Employees>
<Employee>
Emp1
</Employee>
<Employee>
Emp2
</Employee>
<Employee>
Emp2
</Employee>
</Employees>
```

OR

I should represent the Employee like `Emp1,Emp2,Emp3`, split the string, add to a table variable and then insert into the database table.

Are there any performance difference between the two approaches. Please note that this is very simple structure without any nesting of employees in the XML and without more than one delimiter in the string. This XML is also not going to be used as schema or anything. Would OpenXML be the overkill? Could anybody give some direction on this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the SQL Server XQuery support, you can easily shred the XML into bits:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Employees(EmployeeName)
   SELECT 
      Data.Emp.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
   FROM
      @Input.nodes('/Employees/Employee') AS Data(Emp)
```

The same cannot be said of CSV files - so I would vote for the XML approach.

Comment: marc_s, thanks for your time. Do you see any performance difference (XML/XQuery vs CSV) apart from the ease of use in your experience.

Comment: Well, as I said - SQL Server cannot really handle CSV at all (or it gets really really messy with lots of calls to CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING and stuff) - so performance isn't really an issue - with XQuery, you can get it done. With CSV, you need to do lots of work on the client (using an application, a utility or something). If you must work with CSV, investigate things like the SqlBulkCopy class - it should serve this purpose

Comment: @ydobonmai THINK MAINTENANCE. I have used XML approach and it works decently.

Comment: +1 @marc_s, the Stored procedure has calls to a UDF which takes a CSV and returns a table. But Its messy for sure anyway just the mess put somewhere else. When you say, "so performance isn't really an issue", you mean using CSV has got more performance overhead than XQuery/XML?

Comment: +1 TheVillageIdiot. I agree. Thank you for your time. I have been using CSV for this kinda things and now looking to use XML/XQuery and therefore looking for some of the performance comparison to strengthen my confidence in XML/XQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problems with using Table-Valued Parameters are:

1) You cannot modify a User Defined Table Type.  You need to drop and recreate. 
2) You cannot drop a User Defined Table Type if it is being referenced by another object i.e. stored proc or function

Given this, if your UDTT is used in multiple Stored Procs or functions, you need to drop them all, drop the UDTT, recreate the UDTT and then recreate all your SP's.

Answer (score 0):

Well depending on what version of SQL you are using there is a third option that is very easy. If you are using SQL 2008 then you can create a user defined table type.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntegerList] AS TABLE(
    [n] [VARCHAR(100)] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [n] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

I used this with integers but I don't see why you couldn't just change the type to be varchar. Then you use it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckIds]
    @Ids    IntegerList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Table]  
    WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT n FROM @Ids)
END
```

Then in your .net code you set it up like so:

```
int[] Ids = <You id array>
var IdList = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
SqlMetaData[] tvp_definition = { new SqlMetaData("n", SqlDbType.Int) };

foreach (int Id in Ids)
{
    var rec = new SqlDataRecord(tvp_definition);
    rec.SetInt32(0, Id);
    IdList.Add(rec);
}
```

Then pass it in as param like usual to stored proc call except you make some minor changes:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Ids", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, TypeName = "IntegerList", Value = IdList });
```

Might seem like a lot but it is actually not. It is really clean and no unnecessary code of parsing xml or strings.

I can't remember where I originally found this code. I thought it might have been on this site but when searching I couldn't find it. So if someone finds it I will gladly give credit to whomever it belongs to. Just wanted to share because I was not familiar with this in 2008 and felt it was a very clean approach.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in the question. I am using Sql Server 2005.

Comment: Ok well then nevermind. I think this only works in 2008. But I will check really quick.

Comment: Yeah it only works in 2008. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526.aspx

Comment: Right, Its called table valued parameter.